# Transformer - Attention is all you need - encoder decoder cross attention

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, attention-model

It is my understanding that each encoder block takes the output from the previous encoder, and that the output is the attended representation (Z) of the sequence (aka sentence).  My question is, how does the last encoder block produce K, V from Z (to be used in encoder-decode attention aublayer of the decoder)

are we simply taking Wk and Wv from last encoder layer?

http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question. I have trouble understandng the decoder phase also/

Answer (score 0):

I think that for all the first (non-masked) Multi-Head Attention layers of the decoder, $K = V = Z$. But before attention is calculated for that sublayer, $K$ and $V$ are projected into a different space with separate trained parameter matrices $W_i^K$ and $W_i^V$.